# Does using seed to restore a wallet change its address?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, mining

I have been using a wallet generated using monero-wallet-cli on Ubuntu. I have not yet received funds on this address, but have been mining in a pool using this address.
I had a harddisk problem so I used a new harddisk to install Ubuntu on, and restored my wallet from seed.
I noticed the wallet-id that I used for mining on the previous harddisk, is different from the wallet-id that is generated from the 25 word seed. I have tried twice, both times the same (new) id was generated.
As I have not received any payment, I can not check wheter the account balance is the same, but I'd like to receive the mining payments, once my threshold is reached.

Is this normal behaviour? Are the 2 address id's pointing to the same info? A Google search did not get me an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A same seed will restore the same wallet. Checking the address is a good way to check that you got your seed right. For example, the seed

`tanks ticket muffin eclipse lectures degrees gymnast technical deodorant hefty lunar casket zapped bovine skater bypass frying acquire inkling ammo army myriad soggy tepid hefty`

will always result in the address

`4ABD4g9KKzqdXtMdmgKF4pHg1qPthzmtBXiBMKLT3rPT4L7gCAKMZ1yD9nA3JVCVRpWn9X3aZeqKkfX81bemg2V2UQnve4o`.

However, that's a standard address. If you use integrated address (which is just your address + some random data packed in), then it will be slightly different for each different payment ID packed in:

1. `4Kst5UxowGMdXtMdmgKF4pHg1qPthzmtBXiBMKLT3rPT4L7gCAKMZ1yD9nA3JVCVRpWn9X3aZeqKkfX81bemg2V2hVfa2bxWtuzMXeekK9` (payment ID = `1961b07fc64d25b5`)
2. `4Kst5UxowGMdXtMdmgKF4pHg1qPthzmtBXiBMKLT3rPT4L7gCAKMZ1yD9nA3JVCVRpWn9X3aZeqKkfX81bemg2V2hbkcazxrXezR8kXAqL` (payment ID = `ba01b042e8b04bd5`)

and so on.

Even if the letters look different, all these addresses are encoding the same thing. Your public spend and public view key + optional payment ID.

Funds sent to all 3 addresses will go to the same wallet, but the last 2 will come in with a "message" (payment ID).

You can play around to see how it works [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html).

Comment: OK, than I guess I wrote down the seed words incorrectly. A mistake to learn from...

Comment: That's rather strange, since if you make a mistake there's a checksum to alert you. Maybe you mixed up wallets? If you messed up just 1 word it's not hard to restore by guessing.

Comment: Also for me. I generated one year ago a wallet and I made 2 paper backups of the seed. I funded primary address and now I cannot restore my wallet from seed because that seed is generating another primary address totally different from the original I funded.
I'm sure that I double checked each word of the seed.
I can't understand why now the same seed generates a different wallet. I haven't more than 1 wallet. I can't confuse with other wallets because I have generated only this.
I tried to change language of the seed with no results. I tried to restore using precedent release of monero-wallet

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking - As far as I can tell, a wallet recovery using a 25 word seed should always generate a new wallet with the same address and seed. However, if you make any change during the recovery process, it will result in a different wallet.
In my case, I was recovering a wallet using the Monero CLI, and when it prompted me for the "passphrase offset", I mistakenly entered what I thought it was. It turns, I had never actually set this for my original wallet. When I left the passphrase empty (just pressed enter), then my wallet was recovered successfully.